# How to know existing children of an entity in Google App Engine (python)?

Tags: google-app-engine

I made entities in parent-child relationship:

```
# Create Employee entity
employee = Employee()
employee.put()

# Set Employee as Address entity's parent directly...
address = Address(parent=employee)

# ...or using its key
e_key = employee.key()
address = Address(parent=e_key)

# Save Address entity to datastore
address.put()
```

Then, suppose that we only know the address entity and want to get the parent (employee). 
we can get address' parent:

```
address.key().parent()
```

However, I do not know how to get the employee's child when I know employee only. I found that Key.from_path(...) method was for getting Key from parent-child relationship, but I do not know how to deal with.

Comment: Currently I think it is not possible to query children from parent.

Comment: I do see Python in your question, still pasting this link to something similar in Java, if you could implement something similar: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/528650/google-app-engine-query-not-filter-for-children-of-an-entity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can query for (direct or indirect) children using the `.ancestor()` query filter, like this:

```
  addresses = Address.all().ancestor(emp).fetch()
```

Comment: it it faster than just storing parent's id in a child's column and fetch by equality of that column to id?